# Searchable input with dropdown

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

For building a structure like this, I need an input where the user can type and dynamically make requests with every change, **response of which will be displayed in the dropdown options below**, when clicking on any of the options, the dropdown must close.

[image]

Its being built with React, so please don't offer any jQuery solutions like select2. I have tried **[react-select](https://github.com/JedWatson/react-select), semantic UI select and some others.** Right now I am trying to solve the problem with this module https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-select-search

```
class Search extends Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);

        this.changeHandler = this.changeHandler.bind(this);
        this.loadHandle = this.loadHandle.bind(this);
    }

    changeHandler(e){
        let value = e.target.value;
        this.props.setName(value);
        if (value.length <= 1) return;
        axios.get(`https://somelink.com`)
        .then(res => {
            this.props.onGet(res);
        })
    }

    loadHandle(){
        const tourList = this.props.state.tourList;
        return tourList === undefined || tourList.length === 0;
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <React.Fragment>
                <div className="card card-body mb-4 p-4 mt-3">
                    <h1 className="display-4 text-center">
                        Search a Tournament
                    </h1>
                    <div className="form-group">
                        {/* <input type="text" minLength={2} name="tourTitle" value={this.props.state.name || ''} onChange={this.changeHandler} placeholder="Write here..." className="form-control form-control-lg"/> */}
                        <ReactSelect onChange={this.changeHandler} placeholder="Write here..." options={this.props.state.tourList} isLoading={this.loadHandle}/>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </React.Fragment>
        );
    }
}


function mapStateToProps(state){
    return {
        state
    };
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch){
    return {
        setName: tourName => {
            dispatch({
                type: SET_NAME,
                name: tourName
            })
        },
        onGet: res => {
            if (res.data.length === 0) {
                dispatch({
                    type: SEARCH_TOURNAMENTS,
                    tourList: 'empty'
                })
            } else {
                dispatch({
                    type: SEARCH_TOURNAMENTS,
                    tourList: res.data[0].documents
                });
            }
        },
    }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Search);
```

The final result is very much like the default Google search prompt, you write, requests get made and the options appear below the search-bar.
Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: Can you show your code, and clarify what exactly you need help with?

Comment: Yes, already did!
In case of using react-select the modified data isn't available for the component, because of redux's order of actions. The data gets passed from react, right after the component is rendered, so it has no option to get it.

Comment: not sure about this 'order of actions' problem. You should be able to trigger a re-render when the data from api arrives.

Comment: I fixed it by myself, will add the solution in following hour or so. Thank you for your time :)

Answer (score 1):

The multiselect option here seems to do what you want: https://jedwatson.github.io/react-select/

However, if you want something truly tailored to your needs, why not create your own multiselect dropdown?

Comment: Have already tried, unfortunately didn't help.
Short on time, the only reason.

Comment: Sure but it seems to do exactly what you are asking, so perhaps you need to clarify why it doesn't work so that someone can help you?

Comment: Of course, will add some code now. React-select has a very strict data structure requirements, not compatible with what I get from api. And when I try to modify the received data on my client there's an order of actions problem.